# Поделиться ссылкой приложения на Facebook

Tags: android, facebooksdk

Допустим, у меня есть кнопка Share on Facebook.

```
shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

Как я могу через Facebook SDK поделиться ссылкой на Play Market?